# NameError: name 'soma_ab' is not defined

Tags: python

Here there is a simple description of the error

[image]

Comment: It would be useful to post your code here as editable text, rather than a linked image. Since you did not define a function soma_ab, you can’t call it.

Comment: What did you think that was going to do?

Comment: This code is trying to call a function called `soma_ab`, but that function hasn't been defined.  You have three choices:  (1) import it from someplace, (2) define it yourself, or (3) don't try to call it.

Comment: Go over: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1):

this would do for you:

```
def soma_ab():
   return a + b

a = 10
b = 30
soma_ab()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the function soma_ab, a bit like this:

```
def soma_ab():
    # the code your function is supposed to do
```